# Der Rosenkavalier Suite for winds

Tags: classical-music

Many years ago I heard on the radio a suite from Der Rosenkavalier played by a wind band or a large wind ensemble. It was charming. Either I missed hearing who the performers were, or I didn't listen carefully, thinking I could easily find a CD of it. If the latter, I was wrong. I assume it was a recording. Does anyone know what it was, who was performing, was it a recording that can be bought or downloaded somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

I found a concert from last year [Kammerakademie Potsdam, text German only](https://kammerakademie-potsdam.de/event/kammermusik-im-foyer/rosen-zur-hochzeit/) as well as one from this year, labelled "Sequence of waltzes from Rosenkavalier" [Mozarteum, also German only](http://www.blaeserphilharmonie-mozarteum.at/index.php?id=71&L=4).

A searchable term is [Wikipedia: Harmonie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonie) or *Harmoniemusik* in German.
But I had no luck, and the typical era of *Harmonie* precedes Strauss significantly. Ambitious wind bands seem to play it occasionally, however.

The sheet music can be ordered [here](https://www.blasmusik-shop.de/Suite_49), and on the page is also a recorded sample.